# How the api.ai webhook link to my sql?

Tags: php, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm created a bot for facebook messenger and telegram. Its works good. And now i want to fetch data from my site server to compleate the user query. I found many python codes but i want it with php. Please help

Comment: Eg: users want to check application status with the help of BOT

Comment: I recommand that you try to convert the Python code to PHP, nobody here will convert the code for you.

Comment: Nobody knows python here